# Prevent YouTube auto-play with Fancybox?

Tags: youtube, fancybox

If I Fancybox the youtube link (as opposed to embedding the code as normally w/o fancybox) how can I avoid autoplay on pageload?

I want to be able to click the image for it to start playing.

http://www.estherwarda.com/wci/homepage/

Comment: Please post relevant code here, not just a link. It 404's right now anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the latest version of Fancybox (2+), YouTube and Vimeo are now recognized and handled quite well.

However, it took some digging around to find this out since most documentation is on Fancybox 1.

Fancybox strips your YouTube URL and adds some default parameters:

- **autoplay=1** (videos will autoplay)
- **autohide=1** (control will hide once video is playing)
- **fs=1** (fullscreen is enabled)
- **rel=0** (related videos are hidden)
- **hd=1** (HD playback is enabled)
- **wmode=opaque** (fixes z-index with YouTube and lightboxes)
- **enablejsapi=1** (enables Javascript API)

What this means that normally you could pass those parameters in your URL and have them apply, but Fancybox 2 ignores those and falls back on the preset values.

Don't dismay!  You can override those in your script.  Several ways.

**Normal media embed:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          media: true
      }
  });
```

**Custom URL parameters method 1:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          media: {
              youtube : {
                  params : {
                      autoplay : 0
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

**Custom URL parameters method 2:**

```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({,
       helpers : {
          media: true
      },
      youtube : {
          autoplay: 0
      }
  });
```

Look in the helpers > jquery.fancybox-media.js file for more details (check the comments).  Fancybox 2 also supports a variety of URL formats so you don't need to worry about which URL version you should be using (i.e. *youtube.com/watch?v=###* vs. *youtu.be/###*).

Answer (score 2):

It's about your embed code. Youtube's old default embed code looks like that: `http://www.youtube.com/v/bla?version=3`. It can be take autoplay parameter that controls the playing on loading. You can push back `&autoplay=0` to `http://www.youtube.com/v/bla`

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/bla?version=3&autoplay=0
```